# Is white paint the same color regardless of the company?

Tags: painting, paint

I'm painting and have run out of the particular white paint I was using. I have some leftover white from a different room. Is there a way to tell if the white will be the same and match?

Here are the two versions

- Ace Premium Royal Interior Wall + Trim paint Satin Acrylic Latex Enamel 182A100 High Hiding White
- Clark + Kensington Paint + Primer in One Flat Enamel 126S310 Ultra White (Tint Base)Ace

Comment: No, white comes in many shades and hues.

Comment: Also, don't mix different sheens. You'll be able to tell a difference between flat and satin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No two whites are the same.  In fact, sometimes two tins of the same color from the same company can be different! This is why if you are painting large areas, it is best to blend the cans together.

Comment: @Jason This mixing is often referred to as Boxing if you need to further research the term.

Comment: As an example, see the little book of whites from Dulux: http://dulux.trade-decorating.co.uk/colours/ranges/whites/index.jsp

Comment: This is in general annoying.  Many times when doing touch up work, I end up repainting the whole trim section because there are 2 "shades" of white.  Definately a gray area with paint colors.

Comment: Too bad Pantone doesn't make paint :)